# are singleton objects or static properties only the solution of sending datas between two viewControllers while receiver viewController is not loaded?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I'm making simple demo app. I wanted to send selected tableviewcell's product data to next ViewController(ProductDetailViewController).

I thought direct access to property of another viewController was not worth way consider security, so I made custom protocol and used delegate pattern.

my app's rootViewController is ProductviewController and it is data-sender object. unfortunately, because data-receiver object 'ProductDetailViewController' is not loaded yet at execution time of `ProductViewController.delegate?.didReceiveData(productList[indexPath.row])` code, nothing happened.

after ProductDetailViewController is loaded by navigation at least once, data-sending works but it doesn't work at first so it's half success..

here's my code.

this is ProductViewController(data-sender object) :

```swift
import UIKit

final class ProductViewController: UIViewController {

    static var delegate : ProductDetailViewDelegate?
    
    private let productTableView = UITableView()
    
    let productList : [Product] = [
        Product(name: "1907 Wall Set", cellImageName: "image-cell1", fullscreenImageName: "phone-fullscreen1"),
        Product(name: "1921 Dial Phone", cellImageName: "image-cell2", fullscreenImageName: "phone-fullscreen2"),
        Product(name: "1937 Desk Set", cellImageName: "image-cell3", fullscreenImageName: "phone-fullscreen3"),
        Product(name: "1984 Moto Portable", cellImageName: "image-cell4", fullscreenImageName: "phone-fullscreen4")
      ]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemGray6
        setTable()
        setUI()
    }
    
    func setTable() {
        productTableView.delegate = self
        productTableView.dataSource = self
        productTableView.register(CustomTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Reused")
        productTableView.rowHeight = 94
        productTableView.backgroundColor = .systemGray6
        
        let header = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: 18))
        productTableView.tableHeaderView = header
    }
    
    func setUI() {
        productTableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.addSubview(productTableView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            productTableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            productTableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
            productTableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
            productTableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor)
        ])
    }

}

extension ProductViewController : UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return productList.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Reused", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
        cell.productName.text = productList[indexPath.row].name ?? "nonamed"
        cell.productImage.image = UIImage(named: productList[indexPath.row].cellImageName ?? "star")

        return cell
    }
    
    
}

extension ProductViewController : UITableViewDelegate{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        let nextVC = ProductDetailViewController()
        
        ProductViewController.delegate?.didReceiveData(productList[indexPath.row])
        
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextVC, animated: true)
    }

}
```

and this is ProductDetailViewController(data-receiver object)

```swift
import UIKit

protocol ProductDetailViewDelegate : AnyObject {
    
    func didReceiveData(_ product : Product?)
}

final class ProductDetailViewController: UIViewController {
     
    
    var currentProduct : Product?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ProductViewController.delegate = self
    }

}

extension ProductDetailViewController : ProductDetailViewDelegate {
    func didReceiveData(_ product: Product?) {
        currentProduct = product
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a delegate pattern where one should not be used. Never use a delegate pattern to directly send data forward. Your `ProductViewController` needs to directly provide data upon creation of a `ProductDetailViewController`. Since `ProductViewController` directly creates and displays the `ProductDetailViewController`, the `ProductViewController` can directly give the data to the `ProductDetailViewController`. No delegate required. Nothing needs to be static or a singleton.

Your `ProductDetailViewController` class becomes:

```
final class ProductDetailViewController: UIViewController {
    var currentProduct : Product?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

Get rid of the `ProductDetailViewDelegate` protocol and the corresponding `ProductDetailViewController` extension.

Then the `didSelectRowAt` delegate method of `ProductViewController` becomes:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let nextVC = ProductDetailViewController()
        nextVC.currentProduct = productList[indexPath.row]
        
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextVC, animated: true)
    }
```

Also remove the static `delegate` property from `ProductViewController`. Now your code is much simpler and cleaner.

---

Look at `UITableView` for an example of when you would want to use the delegate pattern. Lots of different things can create a table view. The table view doesn't know exactly what will create it. The delegate pattern allows the table view to ask its creator (or any other object set as its delegate) to provide data when needed and it allows the table view to inform its creator about events.

In your case, the `ProductDetailViewController` doesn't need to ask anyone for data nor does it need to notify anyone about any events. Its creator can pass it its initial data on creation and then that's the end of the communication.

---

If you later expand `ProductDetailViewController` such that it does need a delegate pattern to communicate with its creator then you need to fix your original attempt.

- Bring back the `ProductDetailViewDelegate` protocol.
- Add a non-static `delegate` property to `ProductDetailViewController`, not `ProductViewController`.
- Add an extension to `ProductViewController` that implements the `ProductDetailViewDelegate`.
- When `ProductViewController` creates a `ProductDetailViewController`, the detail controller's `delegate` property is set to `self`.
- Where needed, have `ProductDetailViewDelegate` call delegate methods on its `delegate` to get data or notify it of events.